# NFA not working Properly

Tags: nfa

its not giving the correct output.
  on this INPUT, the respective output should be obtained .

Sample output for regExpression: (a|b)*abb

Enter State No (0 to Quit ): 1
  Final State ? (Y?N) N
  Enter State No (0 to Quit ): 2
  Final State ? (Y?N) N
  Enter State No (0 to Quit ): 3
  Final State ? (Y?N) N
  Enter State No (0 to Quit ): 4
  Final State ? (Y?N) Y
  Enter State No (0 to Quit ): 0

Enter Transitions from state 1 
  To State (0 to Quit) : 1
  Enter symbol : a

To State (0 to Quit) : 1
  Enter symbol : b

To State (0 to Quit) : 2
  Enter symbol : a

To State (0 to Quit) : 0

Enter Transitions from state 2 
  To State (0 to Quit) : 3
  Enter symbol : b

To State (0 to Quit) : 0

Enter Transitions from state 3 
  To State (0 to Quit) : 4
  Enter symbol : b

To State (0 to Quit) : 0

Enter Transitions from state 4 
  To State (0 to Quit) : 0

Enter String : abb
  String Accepted.
  Enter String (q to Quit): aaaabb 
  String Accepted.
  Enter String (q to Quit): aaaabbbbbb
  String Not accepted!!! . 
  Enter String (q to Quit): quit
  String Not accepted!!! . 
  Enter String (q to Quit): q

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


       struct state{
       char final;
       int value;
        struct transition *transList;
         };

           struct stateList{
           int value;
                 struct state *statePtr;
            struct stateList *next; 
                 };

             struct transition{
             char symbol;
                 struct state *statePtr;
               struct transition *next;
                 };

           int dfa(char * input, struct state *s);
           void freemem(struct stateList * sList);
       int main(){
       struct stateList *sList = NULL, *sListPtr=NULL, *tmpListPtr = NULL;
        struct state *sPtr, *tmpStatePtr;
        struct transition *tPtr,*tmpTransPtr;
        int stateNo;
        char final='N';
         char symbol=' ';
        char input[80];
      do{
        printf("Enter State No (0 to Quit ): ");
        scanf("%d",&stateNo);
        getchar();
        if(stateNo != 0){
        printf("Final State ? (Y?N) ");
        scanf("%c",&final);
        getchar();
       //printf("\n Final :%c",final);
      if(sList == NULL){
       sList = (struct stateList*) malloc(sizeof(struct stateList));
       sList -> value = stateNo;
       sList -> statePtr = (struct state *) malloc (sizeof(struct state));
       sList -> statePtr -> value = stateNo;
         sList -> statePtr -> final = final;
          sList -> statePtr -> transList = NULL;
         sList -> next= NULL;
       }
      else{
           sListPtr = sList;
           while(sListPtr -> next != NULL){
           sListPtr = sListPtr->next;
            }
          sListPtr->next = (struct stateList*) malloc(sizeof(struct
          stateList));

         sListPtr = sListPtr->next;
          sListPtr -> value = stateNo;
      sListPtr -> statePtr = (struct state *) malloc (sizeof(struct state));
          sListPtr -> statePtr -> value = stateNo;
            sListPtr -> statePtr -> final = final;
         sListPtr -> statePtr -> transList = NULL;
         sListPtr -> next= NULL;
          }
      }
      }while(stateNo != 0);

      sListPtr = sList;
     while(sListPtr != NULL){
     printf("\n\nEnter Transitions from state %d \n",sListPtr->value);
     printf("To State (0 to Quit) : ");
     scanf("%d",&stateNo);
    while(stateNo != 0){
    tmpListPtr = sList;
    while(tmpListPtr != NULL){
    if(tmpListPtr-> value == stateNo){
     break;
     }
     tmpListPtr = tmpListPtr ->next;
    }


   if(tmpListPtr == NULL){
   printf("Invalid State\n");
   }else{
   getchar();
   printf("Enter symbol : ");
   scanf("%c",&symbol);
   sPtr = sListPtr -> statePtr;

   if(sPtr->transList == NULL){
 sPtr->transList = (struct transition *) malloc (sizeof(struct transition));
     tPtr = sPtr->transList;
    }else{
      tPtr = sPtr->transList;
     while(tPtr->next != NULL){
     tPtr = tPtr->next;
     }
   tPtr -> next = (struct transition *) malloc (sizeof (struct transition));
    tPtr = tPtr ->next;
     }
    tPtr -> symbol = symbol;
   tPtr -> statePtr = tmpListPtr->statePtr;
   tPtr -> next = NULL;

   }
   printf("\nTo State (0 to Quit) : ");
  scanf("%d",&stateNo);
  }
  sListPtr = sListPtr -> next;
  }
  if(sList != NULL){
  printf("\nEnter String : ");
  scanf("%s",input);
  while(strcmp(input,"q") != 0){
  if( dfa(input,sList->statePtr )){
   printf("String Accepted.");
  }
   else{
   printf("String Not accepted!!! . ");
  }
  printf("\nEnter String (q to Quit): ");
  scanf("%s",input);
  }
  }

  freemem(sList); 
  }

 int dfa(char * input, struct state *s){
  struct transition * t;
  int accept =0;
  // printf("\nInput: %s\n",input);
  // printf("Value : %d\n",s->value);
  //printf("Final: %c\n",s->final);

  if(s == NULL){
  return 0;
  }else{
   t = s -> transList;
   if(input[0] == '\0' && s -> final == 'Y'){
   return 1;
    }

    while( t != NULL && accept ==0){
   //  printf("State Transition symbol : %c\n",t->symbol);
   if(t -> symbol == input[0]){
    //printf("Transist to the state : %d\n",t->statePtr->value);
    accept= dfa(input+1,t->statePtr);
     }
     t = t -> next;
       }
      }
      return accept;
      }

     void freemem(struct stateList * sList){
     struct stateList *tsList;
     struct state * tstate;
     struct transition *trans, *trans2;
     while(sList != NULL){
     tsList = sList->next;

    tstate = sList -> statePtr;
    trans = tstate -> transList;
    while(trans != NULL){
    trans2 = trans->next;
    free(trans);
    trans = trans2;
     }
    free(tstate);
    free(sList);
    sList = tsList;
      }
       }
```